# Api Platform relations

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

I have a situation that I need a related field from the relation field.

I have 3 Entity:

1. Media Object (imageUrl needed)
2. Author (image)
3. Comment (author)

So when I call `/api/comment/1` I want to se `imageUrl` from the author.

I tried to add
`@Groups({"author_object:read", "author"})` on media entity, and also on image of the author, but no luck...
Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add a group "comment_object:read to normalizationContext in @ApiResource of Comment or to 'normalization_context' of the operations you want to show the imageUrl,
2. Add an annotation @Groups({"comment_object:read"}) to Comment::$author property or if you already have one, add the group name to it
3. Add the same group annotation to Author::$image or if you already have one, add the group name to it
4. Add the same group annotation to MediaObject::imageUrl or if you already have one, add the group name to it

You can use a different name for the group as long as you use the same name in all the above annotations

[The chapter4-api branch of my tutorial](https://github.com/metaclass-nl/tutorial-api-platform/tree/chapter4-api) describes something similar for Employee and Hours registration, a working example is in chapter5-api.